# Adding a header row to a datagrid breaks paging

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I wonder if anyone ever incurred into this.
I adding a extra row to a datagrid header, in order to provide a common description to a group of columns.
I use the following code, but it creates problems with the pager, I.E. the bottom pager is not in synch with the top one.

```
 Sub dgResults_Item_Created(sender As Object, e As DataGridItemEventArgs)
    'http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16049/Merge-Header-GridView-DataGrid

    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header) Then

        Dim mTable = DirectCast(dgResults.DataSource, DataView)
        If (Not IsNothing(mTable)) Then
            Dim colSpan = 4 ' colspan of new header
            Dim colCount = mTable.Table.Columns.Count ' add cell at colCount - colSpan

            Dim dgitem = New DataGridItem(0, 0, ListItemType.Header)
            Dim dgcell1 = New TableCell()
            Dim dgcell2 = New TableCell()
            dgcell1.ColumnSpan = colCount - colSpan
            dgcell2.ColumnSpan = colSpan

            dgitem.Cells.Add(dgcell1)
            dgitem.Cells.Add(dgcell2)

            dgcell2.Text = "Client information"
            dgcell2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center

            dgResults.Controls(0).Controls.Add(dgitem)

        End If

    End If
End Sub 'Item_Created
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to go would be using a GridView
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx